# Debug a cookie getting deleted whilst browsing site

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, magento2

I have a **Magento 2** store where the **cookie notice** keeps reappearing. The notice is hidden when below cookie is set:

```
Name: user_allowed_save_cookie
Value: %7B%222%22%3A1%7D
Domain: .www.domain.com
Expires: 2022-08-20T11:24:09.000Z
SameSite: Lax
```

The cookie notice however will reappear during browsing and checking browser cookies shows this cookie to no longer be set.

I have seen this happen on 3 client PC's running Chrome and can be up to 10 mins to a few hours before it clears itself however unsure the pattern or what is causing this.

Expires set for a year, the cookie has a value, domain looks ok (although has a full stop at the start however apparently that means it should work on subdomains as well). Can see mostly around 40 cookies showing for site so feel it is not hitting any limits.

Cloudflare is running in front of this site and did not notice this problem until pushing it through Cloudflare so wondering if that could cause this kind of issue?